# Why does a dielectric liquid need to immerse the parallel plates in a conductivity cell?

Tags: electricity

For a parallel plate conductivity cell with a liquid dielectric in between, after filling the liquid to the point where it is just enough to fill the space between the two electrodes, does the liquid need to immerse the plates any more above that level? If so, why, considering the surrounding atmosphere is an inert nitrogen gas? One paper i read said its to limit partial discharges, but I don't really understand how these would be caused if its not immersed more than that level while the atmosphere is inert. Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to measure? What voltage are you driving the cell at? Show a circuit

Comment: @laptop2d I'm trying to measure the conductivity/resistivity of the liquid by measuring the current at the measuring electrode opposite to the charged electrode. I'm not sure what voltage i'll use right now since i don't know how much is needed to measure the conductivity of this liquid (r134a) at 25C, but i think it'll be between 500V and maybe 2kV. The distance between the elctrodes will be 2mm.

Comment: dear John D. I hope I gave some useful tips. Feel free to ask more questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R134a is also known as Tetrafluoroethane (CF3CH2F) is used as a refrigerant, film propellant and many other applications, evidently here as a voltaic cell.

Being an insulator, it has all the properties of a dielectric.  the conductance of ionic contaminants is a highly variable parameter since the ppb or ppm levels of contamination greatly affect the charge flow in the medium when exposed to a DC or low frequency AC high E field.  The dielectric breakdown levels are significantly reduced by these impurities and the events called Partial Discharge (PD) have enough energy to breakdown the ionized particles surrounded by an HCF molecule cause separation of these molecules releasing Hydrogen as one of the components.

The Lower Explosive Limit, LEL for such a concentration of H2 in the inert gas or fluid may be somewhere above 4% as it is for Transformer Oil, which is the level of removing an oil filled transformer from service to reduce the risk of  explosions. **Thus filling the void space with an inert gas such as Nitrogen is commonly used.**

Perhaps reducing the volume of N2 in the enclosure allows the vapour pressure to rise to inhibit the release of H2 in the fluid which can absorb a much higher volume mass of H2 and these minimize the H2 concentration level in N2.

A Teflon seal that allows only H2 to pass, is often used in outdoor sealed enclosures with SLA rechargeable batteries to release the pressure of H2 during charging.

In the end, the measure of conductivity due to capacitance by rate of change of the applied current will be constant except for some slight thermal variance. The capacitance May be easily measured and current computed by \$I_c=CdV/dt\$. But it is the ionic conductance that is important that is a measure of the impurity from contaminants. **Thus a slow ramping DC is necessary for the measurement.**

PD can easily be detected with a high speed DSO and probe wire shorted with few turns around the electrode wire fed into 50 Ohm coax and terminated with a 50 Ohm Load, or heard on a quiet channel on an AM radio like a lightning tick, hundreds of miles away.  the rise time will be less than 1ns so the faster the DSO, the larger the amplitude of the current pulse. PD is often calibrated in pC but can also be measured in Watts for the duration of the discharge in [ns]. A slower scope will just reduce the amplitude and stretch out the event,

When the flow of ions does not have enough kinetic energy to ionize and create release electrons abruptly, it just circulates in the conductor and back thru the dielectric. This is the current you want to measure.  The PD is reduced by electrode smooth surfaces and may be affected by sharp edges of the plates where contamination may accumulate.  However a battery ESR is greatly improved (lower) by micro surface roughness from acid etch or similar process.

It should not be affected by heat or current as much as the small gap which increases the battery capacity and the contamination Level on PD rate which increases with reducing gaps. It is akin to a Relaxation Oscillator like a Unijunctuon.

However the PD energy level increases with gaps as the distance for contaminants to be accelerated and “detonate” from impact, releases more PD energy.

Thus there are many tradeoffs in such a design and contaminant filtering/processing is the ultimate challenge.

Final word

I don’t expect any PD at 1kV in your gap but if you ramp up slowly to the 1st PD event (1 pulse per minute) this is known as the PDIV ( Inception Level) and is a measure of the margin before breakdown voltage . (BDV)  In a Battery this is more serious as there is a voltage source that will sustain current above then holding current unless some reverse pulse current is applied. this behaves like a latched SCR until current flow drops below holding current levels. I imagine if H2 is generated rapidly, there needs to be an escape pressure valve just as there is for transformers.

In transformer oil testers with a 2mm smooth gap, it is rated for >25kV and when further refined to remove all moisture and particles is capable of 75kV. But defective contaminated oil will fail with PD well below 25kV before it breaks down.

Comment: Hi Sunny, thanks a lot for the really thorough answer, i understand what you're saying but i'm using a different set-up with pharmaceutical grade r134a, so impurities should really be minimal and should not be much of an issue i think. I'm trying to justify using a concentric cylinder (CC) set-up compared to a parallel plate (PP) design and want to make the point that less fluid volume is need for CC. A paper i read mentioned the need to immerse the plates in PP with the fluid to prevent PD and i was just wondering why that was the case as explained in my initial question.

Comment: Also wanted to ask another question, would really appreciate the help. I wanted to know, assuming there is no impurities, how charge is transported between the electrodes in such a cell with r134a before breakdown. Does the r134a molecule disassociate into an ion?

Comment: Only contamination supports ionic real vs reactive dielectric current. PP insulates the electrodes like a cushion to electron bombardment so the energy is transferred without metallic conduction but rather another series capacitance of purified PP.  A CC should work well with purified PP coating

Comment: umm, think you're confusing the term PP with something? I meant it to mean a parallel plate cell. Sorry i'm a bit confused about what you're trying to say. Are you saying pure 134a doesn't conduct electricity, but surely at a sufficient voltage below breakdown it must since its resistivity is not infinite. And if it does conduct electricity, i was wondering how? Thanks.

Comment: I meant polypropylene

Comment: All pure dielectrics conduct 0 DC current steady state. thus the "leakage" resistance is infinite. This stems from definition of a capacitance which is all insulators.  All leakage comes from impurities from the rate of flow of these accelerated ions per second.  This is a very low steadystate DC current.  "Pure" is an ideal theoretical state. (not a marketing label LOL)  So you are measuring impurities.

Comment: thank you so much for clearing that up for me.

Comment: just to confirm Sunny, sorry for coming back to this but there's still some doubt, when measuring the resistivity of dielectric liquids with resistivities of e.g. 10^12 ohm/m, these resistivity values you're saying are because of impurities present in the test, and are a measure of impurities rather than the inherent value of the liquids? wouldn't that invalidate these values though?

Comment: It could. It is only as accurate as your cleaning process for the container. ( like a baseline noise level)   If you are not satisfied with the results and can prove that it is **not** the cleaning process with some better de-ionized reference liquid, then you can be more confident with the results and investigate the transfer process and container then the source.  I know some suppliers get better results from plastic tote-boxes than cleaned tanker trucks for this reason on transformer oil. But they can safely measure AC breakdown voltage in an instrument.

Comment: Fluid testers like Weidman's may not be aware that PD is the mechanism that creates a large std deviation in results for BDV, but they have a process for cleaning and testing for example 5 to 10 times then start collecting results as PD often eliminates small numbers of contaminants. (and I mean very small qty). But this may or does not apply to your fluid.

Comment: I have no testing experience in R134a so I went to the Omega site and they agree with my assessment.  Impurity concentration levels in PPM are inverse to resistivity.   They controlled the concentration level and measured the change in results. The  contaminant electrical parameters make a difference. e.g. a salt or conductive solid or a solid dielectric each react differently for the same PPM by any unit of measure.  https://www.omega.com/en-us/resources/conductivity-resistivity

Comment: Thanks for the interesting question. So to summarize; parallel or coaxial plates need to be "perfectly" clean, non-reactive, and slowly ramped up in voltage to limit current  while checking for any PD activity by radio or scope as a warning before breakdown.  There is no PD warning in a perfect dielectric and each test result is consistent.  The gas volume should be minimized and replaced with N2 if outgassing is expected and sealed with a diffusion gasket and/or H2 pressure relief.  Humidity should be low to reduce the absorption of moisture if exposed to air. So keep clean and dry.

Comment: thank you for the helpful answers